# How do I post button value to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I want use A-Z buttons on a html page like shown below (only sample and few words)

```
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" A " ONCLICK="A">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" B " ONCLICK="B">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" C " ONCLICK="C">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" D " ONCLICK="D">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" E " ONCLICK="E">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" F " ONCLICK="F">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" G " ONCLICK="G">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" H " ONCLICK="H">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" I " ONCLICK="I">
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" VALUE=" J " ONCLICK="J">
```

when I click on each button I want to post respective values on button to a PHP variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: The `ONCLICK=` is used for Javascript. Listing the values there again is unnecessary.

Comment: You really need to lower case all those tag attributes. `input` instead of `INPUT`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Change the `type` to `submit` and give it a `name` (and remove the useless `onclick` and flat out the 90's style uppercased tags/attributes).

```
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="A" />
<input type="submit" name="foo" value="B" />
...
```

The value will be available by `$_POST['foo']` (if the parent `<form>` has a `method="post"`).

Comment: but its type is "button" and not "submit" ? i did tried with type button and $_POST but doesn't work

Comment: @baTimá: Use `type="submit"` then, exactly as explained in the answer.

Comment: but in my FORM i already have a submit button so i cannot have 2 submit

Comment: @baTimá: This makes no sense. You can perfectly have multiple submit buttons in a form.

Comment: but when you click in any of them the page will refresh and thats not what i want

Comment: @baTimá: then just use ajax?

Comment: @baTimá: Uh, surely you can keep using PHP with ajax. This question makes no sense in such way that I suggest to invest some more time in learning basic web development concepts. If you have a specific question, please press `Ask Question`.

Comment: k thanks, well yeah but you in someway did not answer the right question but ok thanks

Answer (score 8):

Give them all a name that is the same

For example

```
<input type="button" value="a" name="btn" onclick="a" />
<input type="button" value="b" name="btn" onclick="b" />
```

Then in your php use:

```
$val = $_POST['btn']
```

Edit, as BalusC said; If you're not going to use onclick for doing any javascript (for example, sending the form) then get rid of it and use `type="submit"`

Answer (score 3):

As Josh has stated above, you want to give each one the same name (letter, button, etc.) and all of them work. Then you want to surround all of these with a form tag:

```
<form name="myLetters" action="yourScript.php" method="POST">
<!-- Enter your values here with the following syntax: -->
<input type="radio" name="letter" value="A" /> A
<!-- Then add a submit value & close your form -->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Letter!" />
</form>
```

Then, in the PHP script "yourScript.php" as defined by the action attribute, you can use:

```
$_POST['letter']
```

To get the value chosen.

Comment: Will just add that POST does not work without <form></from> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that what you're getting in a POST on the server-side is a key-value pair.  You have values, but where is your key?  In this case, you'll want to set the `name` attribute of the buttons so that there's a key by which to access the value.

Additionally, in keeping with conventions, you'll want to change the `type` of these `input`s (buttons) to `submit` so that they post their values to the form properly.

Also, what is your `onclick` doing?

Answer (score 0):

Using input tag is going to leave the mark on the page. Trying button tag will show the button and also can send the value as well.

```
<button type="submit" value="the value you want" >Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use as:
button type="submit" value="A" name="btn"
input type="submit" value="B" name="btn"
when you will post data use:
$_REQUEST['btn'];

Answer (score -1):

```
    $restore = $this->createElement('submit', 'restore', array(
        'label' => 'FILE_RESTORE',
        'class' => 'restore btn btn-small btn-primary',
        'attribs' => array(
            'onClick' => 'restoreCheck();return false;'
        )
    ));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is good practice to explain code in your answers.