# disable php function with other function

Tags: php

I was wondering if there's a way to disable an existing php-function (or a part) when calling another function.

My situation is the following: 
I have a php search function with a text input. This works fine. (See code below)

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
if(isset($_GET['go'])){
if(preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['search'])){
$input=$_POST['search'];

//connects to database
//selects database table
//searches database
//assigns $results variable

//outputs results:
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo 'results...';

}}}} else {
//connects to database
//selects database table
//searches database:
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
//outputs results (same as above)
}
```

so that's a very short form of my working search function. Below this very search function I have a button that - when clicked - should output the search results for **one specific string**. This works as well. The problem is that when this very button is clicked, it **also** shows the "else-part" of the function above, when I only want it to show the results for that specific string, and no other "table items"... 
Now follows the code for the search-for-one-specific-string part:

```
function results_for_one_specific_string () {
//connects to database

//searches database:
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE Name='string'";
//outputs results (same as above)
}

if (isset($_GET['button123'])) {
results_for_one_specific_string ()
}
```

Just to let you know, in order to call `function results_for_one_specific_string ()` I use something like this:

`<a href="index.php?button123=true" title="">title</a>`

Now my question is: Does anybody know how I can somehow 'disable' the "else-part" of my search function (1st block of code) **only** when the `function results_for_one_specific_string ()` is called? (so that only the results of this function are printed and not the 'else' party of the first function as well)

thank you guys!

Comment: ok mate i need to see more of your code you answer should not be a hard one. but i need to know more about how you think and what are you looking for. please past a full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
$hasBeenCalled = false; // Set a global var

function results_for_one_specific_string () {
    //connects to database
    //searches database
    //outputs results
}

if (isset($_GET['button123'])) {
    $hasBeenCalled = true; // Update global var here
    results_for_one_specific_string ()
}

...

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    //connects to database
    //searches database
    //outputs results
} else if($hasBeenCalled==false){ // Check for global var here
    //outputs all table items (not only the search results, everything!)
}
```

Comment: your answer makes total sense to me, but unfortunately it still outputs the else-part of the search function when I call the 'results_for_one_specific_string' function...

Comment: I think it all depends one when the function is called, before or after the `if(isset($_POST['search'])){` code is run?

Comment: thanks a lot! I just had to add another ´$hasBeenCalled = true;´ to the second if-statement in your answer! Now it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems you're having identical code for searching the custom string as well as for the specific string. If this is true, it would be easier and more transparent to make one function for both cases:

```
function results_for_any_string ($search='') {
if(strlen($search>0)){
//connects to database
//searches database
//outputs results
}
else {
//outputs all table items (not only the search results, everything!)
}
}
```

In the main script choose what you want to use as parameter.

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) $parameter = $_POST['search'];
else if (isset($_GET['button123']))  $parameter = $_GET['button123'];
else $parameter='';
results_for_any_string ($parameter);
}
```

Also if noth buttons are in one form you can submit the specific value also through the same form  and as POST. Not mixing post and get. See for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438216/how-do-i-post-button-value-to-php).