# How to get value of button inside the foreach loop using post method

Tags: php, html, button, foreach, forms, http-post

Objective: Get the value of buttons from **$_POST** method, inside **foreach** loop

```
$projects= 'Project1, Project2, Project3'//from mysql database 
$projectNames = explode(',', $projects); // to separate the project names to display one by one on button.
```

Displaying all the project names on buttons.

```
<?php foreach ($projectNames as $val):?>
<form action="projectSelected.php" method="post" id="project">
<button style="float:left" class="btn-default" value=""> <?php echo $val;?> </button>
```

Problem statement: When user clicks on button 'Project1', program should be able to get the value of button with `$_POST['projectSelected']`.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi , what is your need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the value in hidden, and then post the value

`<form action="projectSelected.php" method="post" id="project">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $val ?>">
<input type="submit">`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Karthik Keyan.

Answer (score 2):

1) change the name of your variables :

```
$Projects => $projects (PHP convention)
```

2) add a trim after your explode function

```
$projectNames = array_map('trim', $projectNames);
```

3) use input submit instead of buttons ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438216/how-do-i-post-button-value-to-php))

```
<input type="submit" style="float:left" class="btn-default" name="project" value="<?php echo $val ?>"/>
```

**Complete example:**

```
$projects = 'Project1, Project2, Project3'; //from mysql database 
$projectNames = explode(',', $projects); // to separate the project names to display one by one on button
$projectNames = array_map('trim', $projectNames);
```

Loop:

```
<form action="projectSelected.php" method="POST" id="project">
<?php foreach ($projectNames as $val) : ?>

    <input type="submit" style="float:left" class="btn-default" name="project" value="<?php echo $val ?>"/>
<?php endforeach ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

DO this:

```
   <button style="float:left" name = 'projectSelected' class="btn-default"
 value=""> <?php echo $val;?> </button>
```

what ever you set the name of button will becomes the key of `$_POST` array