# php isset always returns false

Tags: php, html

I admit I am a newbie but I spent 2 days trying to get the following code   to echo 'pressed or not pressed' when pressing the submit button.
I stripped all irrelevant code and am left with below.
This is really basic stuff and every forum I read suggested my code is correct.
I am just using a laptop with windows 10 and IE connected to a WAMP server.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<title>SystemAdministrator</title>
<link href="pval.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="system_administrator.css" rel="stylesheet">

<?php
//test to see if submit button was pressed or not
if (isset($_post['create_userdb'])) {
   echo 'pressed';
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   echo $username;
} else {
   echo 'not pressed';
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   echo $username;
}
?>

</head>
<body>
<Form name ="form1" Method ="POST" Action ="system_administrator.php">
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="username" Name ="username">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "create_userdb" VALUE = "create_userdb">
</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A button does not return a value to php.

Comment: @YUNOWORK Yes it does.

Comment: $_post['create_userdb'] change this to $_POST['create_userdb']

Comment: Thanks very much, that works.

Answer (score 3):

there is typing mistake of $_post. It should be $_POST

```
if (isset($_POST['create_userdb'])) {
   echo 'pressed';
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   echo $username;
} else {
   echo 'not pressed';
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   echo $username;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the lowercase `$_post` - it should be as below `$_POST`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
        <title>SystemAdministrator</title>
        <link href="pval.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="system_administrator.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <?php
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
            if ( isset( $_POST['create_userdb'])) {
               echo 'pressed';
               $username = $_POST['username'];
               echo $username;
            } else {
               echo 'not pressed';
               $username = $_POST['username'];
               echo $username;
            }
        }
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <Form name="form1" Method ="POST">
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" VALUE="username" Name="username" />
            <INPUT TYPE="Submit" Name="create_userdb" VALUE="create_userdb" />
        </FORM>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

1. `$_post` is wrong. You need `$_POST`
2. The submit-button doesn't return a value to PHP. If you use `var_dump($_POST)`, you can see all the posted data from the form, and `create_userdb` won't be there.

You can simply check for the $_POST array like this if you want to check if the button was pressed:

```
<?php
//test to see if submit button was pressed or not
if (isset($_POST)) {
   echo 'pressed';
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   echo $username;
} else {
   echo 'not pressed';
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   echo $username;
}
?>
```

Edit: So in my case, it didn't return anything. PHP 5.3 installed.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php">
    <input type="text" value="username" name="username">
    <input type="submit" name="create_userdb" value="create_userdb">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Test.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
'username' => string 'username' (length=8)
```

Comment: The submit button does return value. i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438216/how-do-i-post-button-value-to-php

Comment: @artberri How can that be? I just tested this on my machine and the submit button did not return anything.