# Global variable invisible to isset, so I can't use it to change the html when user is logged in

Tags: php

So I'm following this tutorial on how to create a login system. Now I can create an account and I can login, which I know works, since I included an error telling me "itworked":

```
if ($checkPwd === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wrongpassword");
        exit();
    } else if ($checkPwd === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["usersId"];
        $_SESSION["useruid"] = $uidExists["usersUId"];
        header("location: ../index.php?error=itworked");
        exit();
    }
```

[image: the url]

but for some reason, the global variable

```
$_SESSION[useruid]
```

is not being seen, so the code:

```
<?php
            if(isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) {
                echo "<li type='button'><a href='profile.php'>Profile</a></li>";
                echo "<li type='button'><a href='logout.php'>Log Out</a></li>";
            } else {
                echo "<li type='button'><a href='signup.php'>Sign Up</a></li>";
                echo "<li type='button'><a href='login.php'>Login</a></li>";
            }
        ?>
```

is not working. The result just gives me the false result, even though the login has been successful. I have also included:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

before the html.

Comment: https://php.net/isset - returns also false if the variable _is_ set but it carries the `null`  value. You have to debug with that in mind, `isset()` always works as documented. Compare with the many similar Q&A material, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33888048/367456 - You'll always find out its about debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($checkPwd === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=wrongpassword");
        exit();
    } else if ($checkPwd === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $uidExists["usersId"];
        $_SESSION["useruid"] = $uidExists["usersUId"]; /* ["usersU -> i <- d"] */
        header("location: ../index.php?error=itworked");
        exit();
    }
```

typo, as always