# C# - Conditional calls in controller method from a html form

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

This is my first time working on a .net project and I am a bit confused on how to connect the html form with a controller class based on what action the user is taking in the html form.

`cshtml` form

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="DecodeFiles">
    <div>
        <input type="file" name="files" id="inputFile">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Verify</button> // Set different piece of code in the controller method
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Dispense</button> // Set different piece of code in the controller method
    </div>
    <div>
        @ViewData["TextAreaResult"]
    </div>
</form>
```

`controller` method

```
[HttpPost("DecodeFiles")]
public IActionResult DecodeFiles(ICollection < IFormFile > files) {
    ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = "No result.";

    try {

        Control.Initialize();
        Control control = new Control();
        Request request = new Request();
        request.setRequestType(1);

        request.setCommandStatusCode(0); // Set only in case verify button is clicked
        request.setCommandStatusCode(1); // Set only in case dispense button is clicked

        ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = string.Format(" Response {0}", request.getHttpInformation());

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        ViewData["TextAreaResult"] = "Exception: " + exc.Message;
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

How should I conditionally call

`request.setCommandStatusCode(0);` in case verify button is clicked `request.setCommandStatusCode(1);` in case dispense button is clicked

Comment: Long time I haven't done this, but here where I would look first: button tag can have a name and a value attributes. Actually, it looks like this may be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438216/how-do-i-post-button-value-to-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the action parameters to

```
public IActionResult DecodeFiles(int? button, ICollection < IFormFile > files)
```

and then in your cshtml

```
<button type="submit" name="Button" value="0" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Verify</button> 
<button type="submit" name="Button" value="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Dispense</button>
```

you should get the value of the submitting button in your controller

Comment: Should I then simply call `request.setCommandStatusCode(button);` in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111222 by @mkozicki
- and by Maartin Balliauw in https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/11/26/supporting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-aspnet-mvc-view.html