# How can I get the value from a <button> in php

Tags: php

There I have three buttons and when I click them I want to get there value using PHP here's my code

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
  <button name="apple" value="apple">apple</button>
  <button name="windows" value="windows">windows</button>
  <button name="linux" value="linux">linux</button>
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: google `basic form post php`

Comment: sorry, I did not get you

Comment: You should learn AJAX. You would need an `<input name='sub' type='submit' value='submit' />` to do it the lame way. Then it's like `if(isset($_POST['sub'], $_POST['apple'])){ $appleValue = $_POST['apple']; }`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438216/how-do-i-post-button-value-to-php

Comment: @Randombuddy do some research before asking the question, or you will get the negative rating to maintain standard in StackOverflow.

Comment: @PHPglue why would the OP need to learn ajax? isn't that a little too much? the OP should learn first how to process a simple form first

Comment: @PHPglue could I please get an example of getting a value from a button using php pls I don't know how todo this

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
//for apple button or change to windows/linux if you want to get the other value
if (isset($_POST['apple'])) {
  echo $_POST['apple'];
}
```